# HTML Target Windows and Fragment Identifiers

Tags: html

I'm having some trouble with combining fragment identifiers in an URL and opening the link in a new tab with the target attribute. I've tested the following code in both Firefox and Chrome:

```
<a href="/page/somewhere#fragment" target="_blank">Some fragment elsewhere</a>
```

The problem I'm having is that this link doesn't open the new page in a new tab. It just opens it in the current window. I tried removing the fragment so that my link is:

```
<a href="/page/somewhere" target="_blank">Some fragment elsewhere</a>
```

and this opens up a new tab as expected. I'm completely beat as to what the issue is. I can even link to the webpage I'm working on if necessary or provide additional details. I apologize if this question is too simple.

Comment: It works for me. The setting for opening new windows is changeable by the user but I don't recall if you can make it "same window" or not, which I take to mean "same tab".